# Rounding the base of a number in E (scientific)-notation in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it posible to round the base of an of a number in E-notation: i.e.

```
4.454554e-63 ==> 4e-63
```

I know I can do it as follows, but I was wondering if anyone knows of an elegant way of doing it...

```
s = '4.454554e-63'
s.scan((/^(\d*).\d*e-(\d*)/) do |n, p|
  puts "#{n.to_i}" + "e-" + "#{p}"
end
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [% operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25):

```
"%.0e" % s
```

The [syntax of a format sequence](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

> %[flags][width][.precision]type

```
Field |  Float Format
------+--------------------------------------------------------------
  e   | Convert floating point argument into exponential notation
      | with one digit before the decimal point as [-]d.dddddde[+-]dd.
      | The precision specifies the number of digits after the decimal
      | point (defaulting to six).
```

i.e. precision should be `0` in your case

Comment: To help google find this answer, I note that the base can also be referred to as the mantissa

Comment: Worth mentioning: you need to use `#` combined with the field `e` to force the decimal point to show up, such as `sprintf("%#.0e", 1) #=> "1.e+00"`